# Hi, I'm new to python and I'm having a problem about loops and lists

Tags: python, list, loops

Problem:
I'll ask the user for inputs(integers only) and put it on an empty list, and if the user entered "end" end function should be called and the sum of the list should be shown.

My problem is that whenever i enter "end" it goes straight to error "Invalid input, try again!" instead of going to the function "end". Please help me

Here is my code:

```
list1 = []
while True:
    try:
        number = input("Enter a number: ")
        list1.append(float(number))
        if number == "end":
            end(list1)
    except:
        print("Invalid input, try again!")
print (list1)
```

Comment: you must check if you enter "end" before trying to convert it to float. also `end(list1)` is not valid python code, change that for a `break` that will throw you outside the loop

Comment: You'll also want to `break` the loop after you call `end`.

Comment: If the user enters `"end"`, break *immediately* and call `end` *after* the loop. Also, don't use a bare `except`: at least use `except Exception`, and preferably only catch the exceptions you *anticipate* being raised and you know are safe to ignore. (That, or at least *log* the exception until you've debugged your code so you can see what happened.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop and the `iter` function to get input until the user types `"end"`. Any input *other* than `end` will enter the loop's body.

```
list1 = []

for x in iter(lambda: input("Enter a number"), "end"):
    try:
        number = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Invalid number {x}, try again!")
        continue

    list1.append(number)

end(list1)
print(sum(list1))
```

Comment: I'll try this one!

Comment: is there anyway I could get the total of the list without using the "sum" built-in function?

Comment: Just as you append `number` to `list1` on each iteration of the loop, you can add `number` to a running sum.